# How to count days and trigger something after passing certain days in database

Tags: sql, laravel, database, triggers

Im creating this website using laravel and there is an option to add new items to the sell when an item adds the admin can mark it as a new arrival, I want to count 10 days from the date added and when the 10 days passed, I want to item no longer listed as new arrival. How can I implement this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to consider those 2 options:

via Schedule command [Reference-doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)

- Create command/use closure which will query database and update items
- Run this command everyday/every hour

via Job [Reference-doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#dispatching-jobs)

- Create job which will query database and update status
- Once your item is created you can dispatch job with a delay of 10 days.